# xelatex & polyglossia: English hyphenation not loading

Tags: hyphenation, polyglossia

I've just updated my MikTeX installation on Windows 7 what resulted in strange problems with polyglossia. Here's the minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\begin{document}
    This is a test.
\end{document}
```

and the warning message from polyglossia/gloss-english.ldf:

```
No hyphenation patterns were loaded for `English'
I will use \language=\l@nohyphenation instead
```

It obviously works like a charm on my installation under MacOS. It also works just fine with other languages under Windows, e.g.:

```
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
or
\setdefaultlanguage{polish}
```

So, it seems like there's a problem specifically with English hyphenation.

I've checked similar questions. Usually, the solution required to update formats or to install missing language files. However, I believe, it does not solve my problems. English is the main language of the distribution I use and it is available (according to: MiKTeX Options -> Languages). Also, I did remember to both refresh file name database and update formats (MiKTeX Options -> General -> Refresh FNDB & Update Formats). It logged no errors. It also generated the required language.dat, language.dat.lua and language.def files. For English in language.dat it created the following entries:

```
english hyphen.tex
=usenglish
=USenglish
=american
ukenglish loadhyph-en-gb.tex
=british
UKenglish
usenglishmax loadhyph-en-us.tex
```

I'm not sure if it is correct but looks sensible. Additionally, according to XeTeX output:

```
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 72 language(s) loaded.
```

So some hyphenation patterns were loaded but apparently not for English (I do not know how to check specifically what patterns were loaded).

Do you have any suggestions? Definitely adding:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
```

before loading polyglossia solves the problem but I'm not sure which package is used in that case and it does not look right.

Comment: It works fine for me. But it looks very odd that "English" is written with an uppercase E in your log-file. Check if your gloss-english.ldf is really up-to-date -- perhaps you have an older version in your user texmf-tree. Did you run the update manager also as user?

Comment: I did not run the update as user. Obviously, it is logical but it did somehow skipped my mind. After running update as user everything works like a charm. (it turned out I had some obsolete Babel 3.9p files) Thank you so much for suggestions. Can you post it as an answer, pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me. But it looks very odd that "English" is written with an uppercase E in your log-file. Check if your gloss-english.ldf is really up-to-date -- perhaps you have an older version in your user texmf-tree. Run the update manager also as user.